# how can i get Get date text .Not able to get any text on the whole page.Attached Image

Tags: selenium, appium

```
List<WebElement> getAllTextOnPage = driver.findElements(By.id("com.condecosoftware.deskbooking:id/action_bar_root"));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

FOR GETTING VALUE OF SINGLE ELEMENT :

You are finding multiple elements with findElement**s**, instead it should be findElement

Try the below code :

```
String textValue=driver.findElement(By.id("com.condecosoftware.deskbooking:id/action_bar_root")).getText();
```

FOR GETTING TEXT VALUE OF ALL THE ELEMENTS :

**Note:** Not all the elements will have a text value. Some elements might have null value. Below is the code for getting text value of all the elements.

For getting text of all the elements :

```
List<WebElement> elementsCollection=driver.findElements(by.xpath("your xpath"));
    int size = elementsCollection.size();
    for(int counter=0;counter<size;counter++)
    {
        System.out.println(elementsCollection.get(counter).getText());
    }
```

Comment: I want to get All text on that page that's why i user List and FindElements

Comment: @ManishSingh I have updated the answer for getting the text value of all the elements. Please use your xpath in the code. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

adding to Vinod's answer: CSS selectors also work if you dont have an ID/ can't guarantee what the ID will be (if its dynamic say). For example:

```
driver.findElement(By.css(".element:first-of-type")).getText();
driver.click('.element:first-of-type a')
```

Comment: For Appium and mobile app automation can i use CSS locator?

Comment: you can with selenium, im not sure about appium but i should think you still can? it will still be breaking because its looking for multiple. Might not be much help but i noticed you say you want them all - are you using selenium with javascript or node etc? - you could try looping through an array? Found a thread http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8029/how-to-iterate-a-list-of-webelements-and-print-the-values-one-by-one-to-perform

Comment: But i need to get text of the Date in mobile for which i can not use css selecter